# Can I use matplotlib to plot the surface of a 3D body?

Tags: python, voronoi-diagrams, matplotlib

If Matplotlib could volume render, I would not ask this question. But it can't. Can I however instead use Matplotlib to plot the surface of a 3D body? I.e. is there a way to (i) triangulate the outside or 'skin' of this body, and (ii) can that surface be plotted?

Note that the body is regularly sampled in the 3 dimensions (a simple 3D Numpy array) but can be quite complex, with indentations and bits sticking out, etc...

PS: I know there are other packages that can volume render, but I really would like to stick to Matplotlib.

Comment: Isn't [this](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#tri-surface-plots) what you are looking for?

Comment: I think that this question is better suited for StackOverflow. There, I have already answered a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35472146/3358223

Comment: Thanks nicoguaro - very helpful